# Custom clustered annotations on MapKit crash when rapidly dragging the map or changing the zoom-level

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mapkit, mkannotation

After implementing a way to cluster customised annotations, the application crashes whenever the view of the map is adjusted rapidly, by scrolling or changing the zoom-level.

> *-[MKPointAnnotation memberAnnotations]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281396c00*

My guess is that the compiler is trying to retrieve the annotation information, but cannot find the data. As I'm fairly new to Swift, I don't see what I'm missing. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a pretty basic setup to display the map in SwiftUI. In the main file, I call the MapView from **MapView.swift**

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @ObservedObject var store = DataStoreMap()

    func makeCoordinator() -> MapViewCoordinator {
        MapViewCoordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView{
        MKMapView(frame: .zero)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context){

        let location = getUserLocation()
        let chargers = store.chargers

        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.03, longitudeDelta: 0.03)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
        view.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        for charger in chargers {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: charger.addressInfo.latitude, longitude: charger.addressInfo.longitude)
            view.delegate = context.coordinator
            view.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }

    }
}
```

Also included in the same file is my custom annotation class.

```
class MapViewCoordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {

    var mapViewController: MapView

    init(_ control: MapView) {
        self.mapViewController = control
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        //Custom View for Annotation
        var annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView()
        annotationView.canShowCallout = true

        let identifier = "laadpaal"

        if let dequedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
            annotationView = dequedView
        } else {
            annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        }

        annotationView.markerTintColor = .some(.systemBlue)
        annotationView.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "car1")
        annotationView.glyphTintColor = .yellow
        annotationView.clusteringIdentifier = identifier

        return annotationView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause for your crash is that you don't account for other annotations requested by map kit (e.g. `MKUserLocation`). You are triggering this due to the automatic clustering as you set `clusteringIdentifier` to a non-`nil` value.

Just return `nil` when you want to deal with the annotation yourself so `MKMapView` uses the default handling:

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation { return nil }
        if annotation is MKClusterAnnotation { return nil }

        let view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "identifier", for: annotation)
        view.clusteringIdentifier = "clusterIdentifer"
        // …

        return view
    }
```

If you ever want to customize the cluster annotations just add a special case for `MKClusterAnnotation`. And if you show user location don't forget to return `nil` for `MKUserLocation` if you want the default blue dot.

Comment: Sidenote: If you use `dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "identifier", for: annotation)` there is no need for the `if`/`else` block just like in table view delegates.

Comment: Wonderful! Also, the hint to use a special case for custom cluster annotations was very helpful.